# How to avoid NPE due to lombok @Data annotation in a class with final field?

Tags: java, lombok, setter, final

I'm getting null pointer exception caused by:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property private final java.lang.String
```

After some research, I realized that it's happening because my class is annotated with @Data and I have a final field defined within it.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ClassA {
    private String id;

    private final String name = "Name A";
}
```

I'm creating objects of ClassA here:

```
public ClassA converter(InputData input) {
     if (input == null || input.getIdValue() == null) {
         return null;
     }
        
     return ClassA.builder()
               .id(input.getIdValue())
               .build();
}
```

Any suggestion on how to handle this problem?

Comment: It works fine in my case. Are you sure your lombok generated the code? You can check it in `target/classes` directory

Comment: Quite obviously, you will not be able to call a setter an a final member. Since you did not provide the code causing the exception, we cannot tell what the problem is caused by.

Comment: Post your code to create a `ClassA` object

Comment: @yejianfengblue, I've added the code where ClassA objects are created.

Comment: @f_puras, I've added the code where ClassA objects are created.

Comment: Looks ok to me. Any chance you can make the name field `static`?

Comment: Case closed. "name" doesn't need to be final in ClassA. I've defined a constant in the converter and set the value in the builder, just after the id. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach below fixes the issue and also makes more sense in terms of business perspective, which is not in discussion here.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ClassA {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}

public ClassA converter(InputData input) {
     private static final String NAME = "Name";

     if (input == null || input.getIdValue() == null) {
         return null;
     }
        
     return ClassA.builder()
               .id(input.getIdValue())
               .name(NAME)
               .build();
}
```